# There is no effect when setting quality of JPEG compression in CGImageDestination in Apple's Core Graphics/ ImageIO framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, jpeg

I am writing and IOS app where I need to save a CGImage as a JPEG file. It is important that I control the quality of the compression.

I've written the function provided below. It works, in that I get a JPEG file. But no matter what I set for the compression, I am always getting the same result. i.e. the file size is always the same.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
void CGImageWriteJPEG(CGImageRef image, NSString *path) {
    NSMutableData * data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)data, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, NULL);

    float compression = .8; // What I put here does not seem to matter...

    CFStringRef myKeys[1];
    CFTypeRef   myValues[1];
    CFDictionaryRef myOptions = NULL;
    myKeys[0] = kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality;
    myValues[0] = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberFloatType, &compression);
    myOptions = CFDictionaryCreate( NULL, (const void **)myKeys, (const void **)myValues, 1,
                               &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);


    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, myOptions);
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, nil);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);



    [data writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] atomically:NO];

    CFRelease(destination);
    CFRelease(myOptions);
    CFRelease(myValues[0]);
}
```

Comment: Would `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` work? Thats what I've used with no issues.

Comment: My only concern with this would be the cost of converting the CGImage to UIImage. I have to perform this for thousands of images, so efficiency is crucial. Do you know anything about the cost of conversion?

Comment: I ran some tests and conversion from CGImage to UIImage is pretty much cost free, so I think I will go this route. Thanks for the help. I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong with CGImageDestination though...

Answer (score 6):

Try passing myOptions to CGImageDestinationAddImage() instead

```
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, myOptions);
```

It's what I had to do in swift, so I assume it's the same. e.g.

```
let imageProperties = [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as String: 0.8]
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, imageProperties)
```

Updated answer for swift 3

```
let imageProperties = [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as String: 0.8] as CFDictionary
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, imageProperties)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've switched to PNG, since it turns out that that is the right type of compression for me, so I can't verify. But thanks anyway.

Comment: I have the same issue and I can confirm this doesn't work. I do have other metadata I'm adding to the image though

Comment: This is the correct answer. https://developer.apple.com/reference/imageio/1464962-cgimagedestinationaddimage